# How to multi template with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

You know wordpress template system. I'm writing a simple script with Laravel. I'm very beginner at Laravel. I need to more than one template and it must be selectable at admin panel.

I created subfolders at views doc like that:

project/resources/views

- defaulttemplate
- othertemplate
- othertemplate2

I keep template's doc name in the database when one is selected. I want to run the site selected template.

How to I can do it?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. Are you working on Worpress or Laravel?

Comment: I want to do like worpress, opencart etc. multi template system with Laravel.

Comment: Well, template are included in blade using their filename. So you just have to store those filenames (partial or full) in your database, and then use those values in your blade includes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Wordpress has a million lines of code and it's open source. You have to observe their codes from github repo if you have ever never implemented an templating engine as same as Wordpress or any kind of equivalent applications. It's not best practice however you can simply create a new namespace for the view from the app container.

You can boot your namespace definition on AppServiceProvider

```
app("view")->addNamespace("theme",base_path('themes/'.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_FOLDER_NAME));
```

Within this way, you can pass different folders as a view. you have to call your view files via `themes::` namespace.

Let's assume you have a default folder in the themes folder as a default template and there is `index.blade.php` inside of it. You have to call it as a `return view('themes::index')` in the controller. If **DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_FOLDER_NAME** changed, the `themes::` namespace will point to changed destination due to App Service Provider. It's a simplest version of wordpress-like templating. For the best case, you have to observe different kind of open source projects.